# Integrating a transformed skew normal distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I am having a little trouble trying to compute an integral.

The pdf and cdf of skew normal distribution are:

[image]

But, I wish to integrate (get the CDF of) the following:

[image]

it's the multiplied PDF by $x^2$.
I was curious if anyone had a way of solving this problem?

Comment: To get this question answered you should put the equations into the problem (in MathJax) rather than making people look at images.  MathJax (which is the math part of LaTeX) is easy to learn and use.

Comment: If you wish to "get the cdf of" your expression, that would require that your expression is a valid pdf. Are you sure that this is the case (after you have multiplied the skewNormal pdf by $x^2$)?

Comment: It might be a misleading expression. It's not the concept of probability function. I just need to integrate the second expression.